# Prove that if $n \in \Bbb{N}$, n is not a power of 2, and for some $k \in \Bbb{N}$, $2^k$ divides n, then $2^{k+1}<n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, arithmetic

> Prove that if $n \in \Bbb{N}$, n is not a power of 2, and for some $k
> \in \Bbb{N}$, $2^k$ divides n, then $2^{k+1}<n$.

Here is what I was able to do:

Let $S= \{ 1\}\cup\{2\}\cup\{p | p > 2 \}$

S is inductive because $1 \in S$ and $r \in S \implies r+1 \in S$. Therefore $\Bbb{N} \subset S$

$2^k$ divides n, so we have that for some $m \in \Bbb{N}$:

$\mathbf{2^k*m=n}$

$m \in \Bbb{N} \implies m \in S$  **(1)**

$m=1 \implies 2^k *m = 2^k *1 = 2^k$ . And we defined n as a natural number that is not a power of 2, so $m \ne 1$ **(2)**

$m=2 \implies 2^k *m = 2^k *2 = 2^{k+1}$. Here again, by our definition of n as natural number which is not a power of 2 we have $m \ne 2$ **(3)**

By **(1)**,**(2)**, and **(3)**, $m \in \{p | p > 2 \} \implies 2^k *m = n> 2^k *2 $

$\blacksquare$

**Is this correct?** If it is not, could anyone tell me what's wrong or how to improve it?

Comment: What is $S$..?How do you define it?

Comment: $S$ is simply the union of $1$ and $2$ and all number bigger than $2$, the Natural numbers.

Comment: Yes but what does $S$ represent to your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to use S to show that if m is not 1 or 2, then m>2 and use this to prove the statement in the title. Maybe it's wrong or there is a better way.

Comment: The set $S$ you use is already equal to the natural numbers..so i think you must put a property to $S$ for its elements to have

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I just realised that I used the letter 'n' for both the problem and my proof attempt, which makes it confusing. I'll edit it

Comment: It is customary to include $0$ as a natural number these days (although not everyone agrees with that convention). The statement is false for $n=0$. Apart from that your algebra is correct, but the way you have prevented the argument is strange. You can just say that as $2^k$ divides $n$, there is a natural number $m$ such that $n = m2^k$ and then argue that the cases when $m = 1$ or $m = 2$ are not compatible with the assumption that $n$ is not a power of $2$. You don't need to mention the set $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n$ is not a  power of $2$.

Now assume that exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k|n$

Clearly $n>2$ if you consider $k=0$ as a natural number.

Suppose that $2^{k+1}>n$

> We have that $2^k|n \Rightarrow 2^k<n$ and $n=2^ks$ where $s<n$ and $s \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> The inequality $2^k<n$ is strict because we assume that $n$ is not a power of $2$.

So $$2^k<n<2^{k+1} \Rightarrow 2^k<2^ks<2^{k+1} \Rightarrow 1<s<2$$

This is a contradiction because there does not exist a naturar number 'between' $1$ and $2$

In general does not exist a natural number 'between'two consecutive natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll assume that your convention is that $\mathbb N$ doesn't contain $0$, because otherwise $n=0$ would be a counterexample.)  Since $2^k$ divides $n$, there is a natural number $m$ such that $n=2^k\cdot m$. If $m$ were $1$ or $2$, then $n$ would be $2^k$ or $2^{k+1}$, contrary to the assumption that $n$ is not a power of $2$. So $m>2$ and therefore $n=2^k\cdot m>2^k\cdot2=2^{k+1}$.